# Open drop down list upwards if the dropdown is at the very bottom of the screen

Tags: jquery, list

I have a dropdown list.I need it to open upwards if the dropdown is at the very end of the screen's visible area,similarly if its at the top of the screen I need the dropdown to open downwards.

(OR)

If I click the dropdown when its at the bottom of the screen I need the list to open by pushing the screen down to the list visible by itself instead of allowing the user to scroll downwards to see the dropdown list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try tagging the technologies you are using.

Comment: If you are rendering dropdown in table, user will get scroll. Otherwise, you can use http://tlindig.github.io/position-calculator/.

Comment: is your dropdown list a `<select>` input or is it created using `<ul>`s?

Comment: it is not list  on clicking the link a div opens as dropdown